# Displaying pdf from the local directory or database in a <object tag

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to display pdf from local directory or database in a object tag.

My problem is I am trying to display pdf print dialog after pdf is loaded.

This is possible if I load pdf using object tag, but currently my pdf is getting loaded dynamically using response.binarywrite.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

regards
Nilesh

Answer (score 0):

For all browsers:

```
<OBJECT width="720" height="540">  
<PARAM NAME="Src" value="../pdf/sign-va.pdf">   
<embed width="720" height="540" src="../pdf/sign-va.pdf" href="../pdf/sign-va.pdf"></embed></OBJECT>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load pdf file from local directory:

```
<embed src="hukumPdf/2.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="700px"/>
```

Read more example : [Load Document PDF from local directory](http://ilmu-detil.blogspot.co.id/2016/04/menampilkan-dokumen-pdf-pada-web.html)

If you want to load and display pdf file from database. You should create a database to store a pdf file. The field of database it depends on how many information you want to display it.

For example :
A database which store information of pdf doc :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `filepdf` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `category` enum('Peraturan Pemerintah','Peraturan Presiden','Keputusan Menteri') NOT NULL,
  `namefile` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `filepdf` (`id`, `title`, `category`, `namefile`) VALUES
(1, 'KAWASAN EKONOMI KHUSUS TANJUNG KELAYANG', 'Peraturan Pemerintah', 'kawasanekonomi');
```

Then you create a php script to call database to display in your site :

```
<div class="container"> 
    <h2>Contoh Mengload Dokumen PDF</h2> 

    <div class="row">

        <?php 
        $query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from filepdf ");
        $data=mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        ?>

        <div class='col-md-12'>
            <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                <div class='panel-heading'>
                    <div class='pull-left'>Undang-Undang Dasar Negara Republik Indonesia 1945</div>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class='panel-body'>

                    <div style='border-bottom:1px solid #000'><?php echo $data[1]; ?></div>
                    <div><?php echo $data[2]; ?></div><br>
                    <div>
                        <embed src="hukumPdf/<?php echo $data[3]; ?>.pdf" type='application/pdf' width='100%' height='700px'/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

More explanation : [Load dan Display Document PDF from database](http://ilmu-detil.blogspot.co.id/2016/04/php-display-file-pdf-dari-database.html)